# FULLTEXT mysql search not working

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a query that gets comments from a database and displays them based on what the user typed in.

PHP:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE MATCH (comments) AGAINST ('%$user_text%')");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "<div>$row['comment']</div>";
    }
```

This doesn't return any values.  It may be that the comments column in my mysql database isn't set to `FULLTEXT`.  i ran this script `ALTER TABLE comments ADD FULLTEXT(comment);` but i can't verify that the index is indeed `FULLTEXT`

UPDATE (after verifying how table was created):

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL...

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  //these are the last 3 lines
 FULLTEXT KEY `comments` (`comment`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=93 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Run `show create table my_table` to see the current schema setup.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($user_text)`?

Comment: @MikePurcell i have verified that there is $user_text is a string

Comment: @MikePurcell this is what it returns:  string(60) "this is a test comment right here 123453432"

Comment: At first I thought it was data issue, the collation issue, when I get into work tomorrow I'll check for a more refined implementation, right now im just going off of memory and little sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I got it. In your original query you are not specifying an optional modifier, which according to [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), means it defaults to IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE. And according to some docs I have read, and my own testing, IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE will only match 'whole' words.

If you want to do partial string matching, you will have to use the IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier instead. However, there is a limitation in that MySQL cannot search using wildcards prepended to a search string, because they are indexed left-to-right, not right-to-left. So to get your search working, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE MATCH (comments) AGAINST ('$user_text*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

You can read up on boolean fulltext searches [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Also, you should read up on [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to sanitize variables going into your queries to protect from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Kirby: 500 error is something different. Check your php error log, if you don't know where it is, type: `php -i | fgrep -i error` from cli.

Comment: you are the man!  i had the PHP whitespace error and it gave me a line number. turns out i needed to change my echo statement to `     echo "<div>".$row['comment']."</div>";
`

Comment: Ahhh nice. Finding defects 90% of time takes way longer than actually fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the table:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE comments;
```

This will show you the statement used to recreate the table, including indexes.
Also, you specified the 'comment' field in the index, yet the 'questiontitle' in the MATCH condition.

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE MATCH (questiontitle) AGAINST ('$user_text')"
```

or:

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE MATCH (questiontitle) AGAINST ('$user_text' WITH QUERY)" EXPANSION
```

ADDED: You also have a  possible typo

```
($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
```

.. missing the closing parenthesis -> ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

Comment: You should get more output than is showing in your post. How did you run the query?

Comment: The fulltext index is present, so now you need to look at your MATCH condition (see updated answer)

Comment: Are you still querying MATCH(questiontitle)?

Comment: sorry my bad.  nothing is questiontitle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7299/discussion-between-kirby-and-cez)